# How do I disable response buffering in API Management and force immediate flush?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-policy

I have a http triggered Azure Function with a canned response returning a collection of json objects. The response is flushed every 10 objects with a 2 second delay in between.

When calling this endpoint directly to the Function I receive the flushed response immediately with no buffering - 10 complete objects with a 2 second delay.

When I call this endpoint through Azure's APIM the response is no longer flushed immediately. I get partial objects and the response appears to be hitting a buffer which is only flushed after a certain time or size.

How can I force APIM to not buffer the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get a response from Microsoft on an undocumented attribute to disable response buffering. Yet to test this extensively yet, but appears to work.

```xml
<backend>
   <forward-request buffer-response="false" />
</backend>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you [forward request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#policy-statement), set `buffer-request-body="false"` which will disable buffer request.

```
<forward-request timeout="time in seconds" follow-redirects="false | true" buffer-request-body="false" fail-on-error-status-code="false | true"/>
```

Also, do not use [`<set-body>`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-on-set-body-policy/) policy. The inner text of the set-body is buffered in a memory stream and delivered to the recipient.

Comment: I'll give the `buffer-request-body="false"` a go but from what I've read this is to do with buffering the request for use with retries, not the response. It's also set to false by default.