# Streaming response is not working in Azure APIM

Tags: .net, azure, api, azure-api-management

We have implemented a simple Dotnet API to provide a streaming response and it works as expected when we test the API directly using the App service Url using the curl command.

The streaming response is not working when we invoke the api endpoint routed through the Azure APIM. We are getting the response in one chunk instead of word by word response.

Is there any setting in the Azure APIM to support streaming response?

Api code

```
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class NewStreamingController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("NewStream")]
        public async Task GetStream([FromBody] MasterInput request)
        {
            for (var counter = 0; counter < request.Count; counter++)
            {
                var message = $"data - {counter} \n";
                await Response.WriteAsync(message);
                await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
        }

        public class MasterInput
        {
            public int Count { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Curl command to test

```
curl -X "POST"  "https://localhost:7152/NewStreaming/NewStream"   -H "accept: */*"   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -d "{ \"count\": 15 }"
```

Comment: define what you mean by "broken or not working". what is the response when you make the POST api call after you deploy to APIM ?

Comment: I am getting the response in one chuck and not getting streaming response.

Comment: check if you have enabled 'response buffering'. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343356/how-do-i-disable-response-buffering-in-api-management-and-force-immediate-flush

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62929137/14973743, your code awaits which will block and not yield. the mentioned answers suggest to add configureAwait(false), try adding it.

Comment: Disabling the buffer response did the trick. Thank you sharing the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APIM supports streaming the response content. In the APIM backend `policy` statement, set the `buffer-response` attribute to false. The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/forward-request-policy#attributes).